# Magento get numerical order of products in collection

Tags: php, magento, templates, collections

In product/list.phtml I'm attempting to get the number of each product as it would appear in the view to the user. Let's say a category has 24 products. If the user proceeds to page two, the first product would be 17 (and the toolbar pager will show 17-24 of 24 Products). I am trying to get that first number.

My issue is that I cannot get an accurate numerical listing. The toolbar pager calculates and displays the correct product numbers currently being viewed, I thought I would just try calling the block and getting the information from it. I figured it would be as simple as calling:

```
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getFirstNum();
```

That returns the error `Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPageSize() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php on line 192`.

That points to this function, the return statement is line 192:

```
public function getFirstNum()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    return $collection->getPageSize()*($collection->getCurPage()-1)+1;
}
```

Digging further it appears that the pager block needs to have a collection set before it can do any operations. So I set the collection and hope it works:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->setCollection($_productCollection)->getFirstNum();
```

Now I'm getting output, but `pageSize` is set to 10, which is causing the advancement of the numbers to be different (and incorrect) from the toolbar pager. In the Admin Panel I have Grid and List default Products per Page set to 16 which is what I was expecting it to be and that is the number the toolbar pager is operating on.

What do I need to do to get a correct and accurate numerical listing?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but give it a try:

Replace:

```
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->setCollection($_productCollection)->getFirstNum();
```

with:

```
$pager = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->setCollection($_productCollection)->setPageSize(16)->getFirstNum();
```

If curPage isn't set correctly you can try ->setCurPage($your_page_variable) after setPageSize(16).